# Copy text from msgid to msgstr in .PO file using PHP

Tags: regex, gettext

I want to copy the string from `msgid` in `msgstr`. Nothing, just to clone it. I need this to be done using PHP. I think here should help regex, but I'm have no idea how to use it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
msgid ""
"We're truly sorry, but there is no such page.<br /> It might have been "
"removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."
msgstr ""

msgid "Private messages"
msgstr ""

msgid "Settings"
msgstr ""

msgid "Article submitted by %s"
msgstr ""

msgid "My articles"
msgstr ""
```

Comment: I am afraid this cannot be done with regex only. You should be aware that PO format also defines different number of `msgstr[n] ""` for different plurals. You should create or use a dedicated PO parser. See https://github.com/MAXakaWIZARD/PoParser.

Answer (score 1):

Use `msgen`, which is the dedicated tool for exactly that. Use `exec()` or `proc_open()` to call it.

This may be stretching the definition of “do it in PHP” a bit, but really, it would be a bit stupid to reinvent the wheel instead of just running a perfectly standard CLI tool that you can easily install on any Linux server...